# JAX-RS validation messages when in interface

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard 1.0.6 application. I want to put all JAX-RS and validation annotations on an interface and then register my resource to implement this interface, similar to:

```
@Path("/user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface UserEndpoint {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    Response createUser(
        @FormParam("username") @NotEmpty @Email String username,
        @FormParam("password") @Size(min=4) String password);
}
```

and the resepective resource:

```
public class UserResource implements UserEndpoint {
    public Response createUser(String username, String password) {
        //my logic here
    }
}
```

This works amazingly, except for the validation messages in the error responses, which have become:

`createUser.arg0 not a well-formed email address`

while I would expect them to be:

`form field username not a well-formed email address`

**UPDATE:**

If I add the JAX-RS and validation annotations straight to `UserResource`, then the validation message is what I would expect: it reports the name of the parameter as specified in the `@FormParam` annotation. This is what I want to achieve, but having the annotations in the interface.

Comment: So you get the desired message when you aren't using an interface?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The message I would like is the one if I didn't use an interface and all the annotations were on the resource.

Answer (score 3):

Annotations are not inherited, unless they are annotated with [@Inherited](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.3).
Per the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html)

> Annotation inheritance only works on classes (not methods, interfaces, or constructors)

So it is up to the code that wants to use the annotations if it will check the parent class/interface for annotations.

In other words you will need to contribute to Dropwizard to make it search annotations from parent classes/interfaces

Answer (score 1):

the real name of the parameters is not available for the JVM at runtime so that's why it is replaced by arg0 , in order to fix this issue you'll had to deal with [ParameterNameProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider.html) which will use reflection in order to return a list of String from `getParameterNames(Method yourExceptionImpl)`

Comment: If I had the annotations on the resource itself, then the validation messages would use the name from the respective `@XXXParam` annotation, in my case `@FormParam`. I was wondering why this doesn't work when then annotations are on the interface. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: This is why specification says to always repeat annotation better on relying on inherited ones